# How to implement bilingual in Messagebox.show() in zk?

Tags: java, multilingual, messagebox, zk, zul

I am using   `Messagebox.show()`  in my application .But my issue is that our application support bilingual just  english and french .I use `pageResourceBundle.getText()`  for bilingual support  in my code  "CONFIRMATION_MSG" work fine for bilingual but the  `Messagebox.YES | Messagebox.NO`  button can not change english to french .

Here's example :

```
Messagebox.show(pageResourceBundle.getText("CONFIRMATION_MSG"), pageResourceBundle.getText("ALERT"), Messagebox.YES | Messagebox.NO,
                    Messagebox.QUESTION, new org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.EventListener<Event>() {
                        public void onEvent(Event evt) throws InterruptedException {
                            if (evt.getData().equals(Messagebox.YES)) {
//code here

}
```

Anyone have any idea  how to implement in the `Messagebox.YES | Messagebox.NO` button to bilingual .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zk already support the bilangual in the messagebox.
You just have to set you Locale to the right one.

Why don't you use the provided i18n in zk?

[http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/Internationalization/Labels](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Internationalization/Labels)